# Could you tell me the name of this compound please?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, polymers, identification

Could you please tell me make of this compound?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is a branched polypropylene glycol terminated with amine groups, a type of polyetheramine, available from BASF as [Baxxodur® EC 310](https://products.basf.com/global/en/ci/baxxodur-ec-310.html), or trimethylolpropane tris[poly(propylene glycol), amine terminated] ether (polyethera­mine T 403) with CAS No. 39423-51-3. BASF markets it as a curing agent primarily for epoxy systems.
There is only one branching point, so it could be considered a single-generation [dendrimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrimer), except that it lacks perfect symmetry.

The image seems to be from the [Sigma-Aldrich website](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/SE/en/product/aldrich/406708) (Merck):

[image]

There you can purchase the polymer with $M_n=440$ which has a degree of polymerization on each branch of ~n=1.8.